# Distributed Map/Reduce framework

Tags: c#, wcf, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-storm

I'm looking for .net distributed map/reduce framework. I intend to use this for a real time data querying and to parallel process the query on multiple nodes.  I'm  currently using WCF for the communication between the web tier and app tier.

For example, If I have 5 nodes with in memory data. If I pass a filter to the 5 nodes. The filter is executed on a chunk of the data the node has and the results are reduced back to final answer.

Just wondering If there is already a framework which can map the jobs and reduce the results back.  I was looking more like a Nimbus of the storm (Twitter real time map/reduce). Can't use nimbus because of many complications. And Zookeeper has too much overhead.

I'm trying to achieve the following using the framework
1) Map the job (mostly a request sent to all the available nodes) to the available nodes and reduce the results.
2) On a fail over map the job to a new node.
3) Manage the cluster. (If a node is down remove it from the list of available servers)

The data will be in memory so I don't need a Distributed file system. A .NET with WCF as communication underneath would be ideal but if there are other frameworks (any language) Please let me know.

Any help (Framework, code project, research papers, actual code :) ) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your comments on nimbus/zookeeper mean as these are management components.

Storm does sound suitable for your use case, but so does others like Hazelcast. I'd need more info on your needs to see which of the solutions might be suitable.

I guess one of the important questions would be what you mean with real time. If you just need short response time and need to work with lots of data, Hazelcast maybe better. If you have  unstructured data coming in that you have to parse/process and make available to the user quickly, then Storm might be a better fit.

Comment: Thanks Enno Shioji. Hazelcast is close for what I'm looking for.  What I meant by real time for example if a user hits a dashboard and say there are 4 charts on the dashboard and if we have 4 nodes on the cluster the job is mapped to the 4 nodes (each node process one chart) and results (4 charts) are reduced back to the dashboard. I'm looking for the framework which keeps track of the avaialble nodes in the cluster and maps the jobs to them.